# How to iterate over a list of lists and calculate the length of the list using jinja

Tags: python-3.x, jinja2

I am trying to find a way to iterate over a list of lists and filter the sub-lists of a specific length.
Rather than the conventional loop method, I am looking for an equivalent to a list comprehension in Jinja. I explored the `selectattr`filter but with no success.

E.g.: with the data

```
{% set lisname = [['a','b','c'],['d','e'],['a']] %}
```

I am looking for a one-liner to filter the sub-lists that are of length `3`.

My current code is:

```
{{ lisname|selectattr(lisname)|list|length }}
```

However, this does not work.

Comment: The question is why doing such a complex task in Jinja, when you can do it in a controller / backend model? In Ansible, you could achieve it because they added a [`zip`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/collections/ansible/builtin/zip_filter.html) filter, but in pure Jinja, I am not sure if this is possible.

Comment: This said if, in your sub-lists there is exactly one item of length `3`, there might be a way I can see.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for the late reply. I tried several ways but could not find a solution yet. But I moved on by using a for loop.